# sqlplus removes extra whitespace

Tags: bash, oracle, unix, whitespace, sqlplus

I have a below test ksh file

```
#!/bin/ksh
(
sqlplus -s << EOF
    ${DATABASE}
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    SET HEAD OFF
    SET FEED OFF
    SET DEFINE OFF
    SET PAGES 0
    SET COLSEP ";"
    WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE      
    SELECT 'aaaa  vvvv   cccc'  FROM DUAL;          
    EXIT
EOF
) | while read sql_out
    do
        echo ${sql_out} 
    done
```

The expected output is

```
aaaa  vvvv   cccc
```

however the output  observed is

```
aaaa vvvv cccc
```

Sqlplus is stripping out extra white spaces from my output and I want to preserve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't SQL*Plus doing that, it's the shell. You need to [enclose your variable in quotes](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#WHITESPACEREF):

> To preserve *whitespace* within a string or in a variable, use [quoting](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quoting.html#QUOTINGREF).

So instead of

```
echo ${sql_out}
```

do either of these:

```
echo "${sql_out}"
printf "%s\n" "${sql_out}"
```

and the output will then be:

```
aaaa  vvvv   cccc
```

Comment: Don't do `printf "${sql_out}\n"` -- the first argument to printf is the format specifier: if the variable's value contains `%`, the results will most likely be not what you expect.

Comment: so nice ... I've ben focusing on `SELECT 'aaaa  vvvv      cccc'  FROM DUAL` ...  +1